Gaps between hardwood floors
I have about 800 sqft of hardwood flooring that is quite old that I want to sand down and refinish. However, I have these large gaps that go almost about 1/6 - 1/8 of an inch. After sanding this down with a drum sander, how do I go about filling these gaps?
I've watched some youtube videos but the gaps are small, my gaps are larger. Is is fixable? Do I use wood putty?
